# Populate PHP Array with multiple Rows

Tags: php, arrays, joomla, joomla3.2

I am running a SQL Query in php and returning the results like this

```
Name
Joe
Jack
Jerri
Jerry
```

I need to parse this into a php array and unfortunately, the method I have used in the past to add to a php array is no longer relevant since I am returning multiple rows.  How would I alter this syntax in order to account for one column with multiple rows to populate my php array?

```
$rows = $db->loadRowList();
$output = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) { array_push($output, $row); }
$data = json_encode($output[0]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Use [`loadAssocList('id', 'name')`](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#loadAssocList.28.24key.2C_.24column.29)

---

> [`loadRowList()`](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#loadRowList.28.29) returns an indexed array of indexed arrays from the table records returned by the query

Thus, I'll assume the `$rows` array looks something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Joe
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jack
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jerri
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jerry
        )
)
```

You can use PHP's `array_column()` to fetch a single index value from every child array:

```
$rows = $db->loadRowList();
$output = array_column($rows, 0);
```

`$output` should now contain an array looking like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Joe
    [1] => Jack
    [2] => Jerri
    [3] => Jerry
)
```

An improvement we can make here is to maintain an associative array, that maps your database's column names to their values. [`loadAssocList()`](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#loadAssocList.28.29) can help there.

```
$rows = $db->loadAssocList();
$output = array_column($rows, 'name');
```

Note that we now use the `"name"` index instead of `0`.

This can be even further improved by utilizing the parameters of `loadAssocList()`:

> [`loadAssocList($key, $column)`](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#loadAssocList.28.24key.2C_.24column.29) returns an associative array, indexed on 'key', of values from the column named 'column' returned by the query

Using this method, we can receive a single array in `ID => Name` key value format:

```
$ouput = $db->loadAssocList('id', 'name');
```